# Getting NULL terms when accesing TermCollection from SharePoint Online via CSOM in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-functions

I am trying to expose a REST API using Azure Functions which returns terms from a specific termset in SharePoint Online using CSOM and C#.

**I can definitely invoke this exact same CSOM code from a console app and from an Azure API app and it is able to loop through the terms and output to console or the HTTP response successfully.**

However, when the code below is invoked from the Azure Function host, it **ALWAYS** find a collection of NULL term objects, when looping through the `TermCollection` or the `IEnumerable<Term>` (I’ve tried by using  `ClientContext.LoadQuery` on `TermSet.GetAllTerms()`, as well as by just loading the `TermCollection` via the `TermSet.Terms` property).

As soon as the iterator hits a term in the foreach (which I’ve also tried as just a LINQ Select), it thinks that the item is NULL, so calling properties on it throws the `NullReferenceException`.  I cannot reproduce the behavior from the console app or from the API app calling into the same code - it just works as expected there and retrieves each `Term` object.

Why is this happening when SAME CODE is invoked from different hosts??
Why would this happen in the Azure Functions host, but not in Console app or the Azure API app?

What is the difference when invoked from an Azure Function host??

I would really like to use Azure Functions for the consumption pricing benefits, so I don't have to host this in an App Service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;

namespace CsomTaxonomyHelper
{
    public class TermSearch
    {
        private readonly ClientContext ctx;
        public TermSearch(ClientContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            ctx = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TermViewModel> GetTerms(Guid termSetId)
        {
            var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(ctx);
            var termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            var termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(termSetId);

            //get flat list of terms, so we don't make recursive calls to SPO            
            var allTerms = ctx.LoadQuery(termSet.GetAllTerms().IncludeWithDefaultProperties());
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            return ToViewModel(allTerms);
        }

        static IEnumerable<TermViewModel> ToViewModel(IEnumerable<Term> allTerms)
        {
            var results = allTerms.Select(term => new TermViewModel
            {
                Id = term.Id, //BOOM! <-- within the context of an Azure Function the "allTerms" IEnumerable is a list of nulls
                Name = term.Name,
                ParentId = TryGetParentId(term)

            });

            return results;
        }

        static Guid? TryGetParentId(Term term)
        {
            try
            {
                if (term.Parent.IsPropertyAvailable("Id"))
                    return term.Parent.Id;
            }
            catch (ServerObjectNullReferenceException) { }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class PasswordString
    {
        public SecureString SecurePassword { get; private set; }
        public PasswordString(string password)
        {
            SecurePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
            {
                SecurePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            SecurePassword.MakeReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the "run.csx" function, invoking the code above which has been compiled into a DLL and placed in the Bin folder of the Azure Function:

```
#r "CsomTaxonomyHelper.dll"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;
using CsomTaxonomyHelper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

static TraceWriter _log = null;
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    _log = log;
    _log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. Getting mmd terms from SPO...");


    var terms = GetFocusAreas();
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(terms);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}

static IEnumerable<TermViewModel> GetFocusAreas()
{
    string spSiteUrl = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SPOSiteUrl", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    string userName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SPOUserName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    string password = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SPOPassword", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

    var securePwd = new PasswordString(password).SecurePassword;

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(spSiteUrl))
    {
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePwd);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        _log.Info("Logged into SPO service.");

        var search = new TermSearch(ctx);
        try
        {
            var result = search.GetTerms(new Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Project.json:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM": "16.1.6112.1200"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the local debugger, when using the Azure Functions CLI to debug this (you can see that it did find 10 items in the collection, but all items are null):

[image: local debugger with Azure Function CLI]

Comment: Could you share your project.json?

Comment: {
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM": "16.1.6112.1200"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I've fired up Fiddler, and compared the responses of the console app client calling SPO, vs. function client calling SPO.  BOTH returned the expected data.  Seems like the issue is in the JSON deserialization?

Comment: That is my suspicion as well. Does that match the reference you have on your custom assembly?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante yes - I'm using the same CSOM nuget package version and targeting .NET 4.6 on all of my test cases.

Comment: We *may* be running into an issue because of the load context used by private assemblies. Just something to try... can you try to move that assembly to another folder (e.g. sharedbin at the root) and reference that using that new path (in this case, #r "..\sharedbin\CsomTaxonomyHelper.dll")?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante when I move my custom DLL to root\sharedbin, the runtime does not load the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll from the nuget package any longer, so it can't find the DLL to load.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante ok, I think you meant to say "..\shared\bin", in which case, for me to resolve the CSOM libs, I can't use the nuget pkg, and have to include the DLLs in the shared bin folder along with my private dll. Doing that worked, and I loaded the terms.  Is there a way to still use nuget with the shared bin assemblies?

Comment: I'm talking about ..\sharedbin. As long as you have the proper package references, mixing shared assemblyes and NuGet packages should work without any issues.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante so, using the sharedbin folder for my custom assembly, coupled with nuget package for the Sharepoint CSOM in the app project.json doesn't seem to work.  It cannot find the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client reference.

Comment: We may need to move to a GitHub issue (at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script) so we can iterate on this a bit more... I would like to get a repro for this together so I can take a closer look, but there's a bit of setup for the environment which makes this  a bit more challenging. I want to confirm, though, you have your custom assembly in a sharedbin folder, a reference #r "..\sharedbin\assembly.dll" and the NuGets in your project.json, correct? If you could share the structure on GH, that would help.

Comment: agreed. i'll open an issue on GH and share my func structure. thx!

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1217

Comment: Thank you! Will investigate with the information you have there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not the solution, but adding to the conversation - I was able to test with PnP-PowerShell (2017-Feb).  Terms were just added.

SPO, CSOM and PnP-PowerShell.

Installing PnP-PowerShell to a PowerShell function:

[image: Drag and drop from windows to modules subfolder]

Comment: how do you add the PnP PS module into Az Functions? (I assume not a nuget pkg, right?)

Comment: haha that's a @ling-toh question.

drag and drop DLL from C:\Users\john.liu\AppData\Local\Apps\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline into a modules subfolder under the function.

more notes here:  http://johnliu.net/blog/2016/11/build-your-pnp-site-provisioning-with-powershell-in-azure-functions-and-run-it-from-flow

also.  lots of PnP Dll will cost more storage.  May be $0.05.  But it's just faster to test things.

Comment: I was able to create and succesfully run a PowerShell version like you did and it returned my MMD terms as expected.  There must be something wrong in the internal JSON serialization when running from the C# script host.

Comment: it's a bummer that I need to call GetAllTerms, because I have nested terms and don't want the long wait of recursive calls to load up my terms, otherwise I'd use this Powershell version.

Comment: PnP-PowerShell returns the same CSOM objects as your C# version.  You can take them and mix as well.  PnP-PowerShell is just a wrapper.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Taxonomy/GetTermSet.cs